# Formatter not called after table refresh

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

After I create a new record in the Database via my SAPUI5 Application, the formatter is not called. The Table refreshes and the new Data is visible but the buttons are not enabled correctly.

See Pictures.

[image: Before_manually_refresh]
[image: After_manually_refresh]

Here's some code:

**Refresh Code:**

```
this.byId("Table").getBinding("items").refresh();
```

**Formatter:**

```
blockedFormatterFrom: function (value) {
        var datum = new Date();
        var dateString = value.substr(6, 4) + "." + value.substr(3, 2) + "." + value.substr(0, 2);
        if (new Date(dateString) < datum) {
            editable_from = false;
        } else {
            editable_from = true;
        }
        return value;
    },
    blockedFormatterTo: function (value) {
        var datum = new Date();
        var dateString = value.substr(6, 4) + "." + value.substr(3, 2) + "." + value.substr(0, 2);
        if (new Date(dateString) < datum) {
            editable_to = false;
        } else {
            editable_to = true;
        }
        return value;
    },
    editableFormatterEdit: function (value) {
        if (editable_from && editable_to) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    editableFormatterDelete: function (value) {
        if (editable_to) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**XML-View**

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="buhler.Order_Matrix.controller.View_ZSCORDERING" displayBlock="true">
<App id="idAppControl">
    <pages><Page title="{i18n>title}">
            <content>
                <Table noDataText="Keine Daten gefunden" items="{ path: '/ZSCORDERINGSet'}" id="Table" >
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar class="sapMTBHeader">

                            <Button tooltip="View Sort Settings" icon="sap-icon://sort" press="handleSortButtonPressed"/>
                            <Button tooltip="View Filter Settings" icon="sap-icon://filter" press="handleFilterButtonPressed"/>
                            <FlexBox class="alertsTablePagination" justifyContent="SpaceAround">
                                <Button id="policyChangeBtn" class="alertbutton" text="New" enabled="true" press="onNewPress"/>
                            </FlexBox>
                        <content>
                            <SearchField width="50%" search="onFilterMatrix" placeholder="Suche Verkaufsorganisation"/>
                        </content>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <infoToolbar>
                        <Toolbar id="vsdFilterBar" visible="false">
                            <Text id="vsdFilterLabel"/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </infoToolbar>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem type="Active" id="item0">
                            <cells>
                                <Text text="{Vkorg}" id="text3"/>
                                <Text text="{ZzscSpSas}" id="text4"/>
                                <Text text="{path:'ValdFrom', type:'sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime', constraints: {displayFormat: 'Date'}, cet: true, formatter: '.blockedFormatterFrom'}" id="text5"/>
                                <Text text="{path:'ValdTo', type:'sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime', constraints: {displayFormat: 'Date'}, cet: true, formatter: '.blockedFormatterTo'}" id="text6"/>
                                <Text text="{ZzscIcSas}" id="text7"/></cells>
                                <Button text="Edit" press="onEditPress" enabled="{path: 'a', formatter: '.editableFormatterEdit'}"/>
                                <Button text="Delete" press="onDeletePress" enabled="{path: 'a', formatter: '.editableFormatterDelete'}"/>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                    <columns>
                        <Column id="column1">
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Verkaufsorganisation" id="label0"/>
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="column2">
                            <header>
                                <Label text="SAS Supplier" id="label1"/>
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="column3">
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Gültig ab" id="label2"/>
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="column4">
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Gültig bis" id="label3"/>
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="column5">
                            <header>
                                <Label text="SAS Intercompany" id="label4"/>
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Edit"/>
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Delete"/>
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                </Table>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

How can I refresh the Table and run the formatters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code below solved your issue ?

```
this.byId("Table").setModel(oModel);
this.getView().byId('Table').rerender();
```

I tried to replicate your issue, but I didn't encountered it. Once I refresh the model, the **list** is being updated, and my custom formatter is being triggered. See below sample:

**manifest.json**

```
"dataSources": {
    "mainService": {
        "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZHR_MY_WORKSCHEDULE_SRV/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "odataVersion": "2.0",
            "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
        }
    }
}
......
"models": {
    "": {
        "dataSource": "mainService",
        "settings": {
            "defaultCountMode": "Inline"
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Page title="{i18n>title}">
    <headerContent>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://refresh" tooltip="Share" press="onRefresh" />
    </headerContent>
    <content>
        <List items="{/WorkSched_PendingSet}">
           <StandardListItem
              title="{EmpName}"
              description="{
                 path : 'Position',
                 formatter : '.formatter.fnFormatDescription'
              }"
              type="Active">
          </StandardListItem>
        </List>
    </content>
</Page>
```

**Controller**

```
return Controller.extend("com.demoDemo.controller.View1", {
    formatter : Formatter,

    onRefresh : function() {
        this.getView().getModel().refresh();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you also share the XML view? 
Try to force the refresh with `this.byId("Table").getBinding("items").refresh(true);`

Comment: Have you tried the this.getView().byId('Table').rerender() ?

Comment: Does 'a' field, belong to your '/ZSCORDERINGSet' entity?

Comment: @TakaoBaltazar rerender doesn't work and what do you mean with 'a' field ?

Comment: I see, The 'a' field, that is binded to your enabled property button. This is your main issue right? am I correct?

Comment: @TakaoBaltazar The main issue is that if I create a new record it doesn't show up and if it shows up with some code the formatters are not called.

Comment: Is your Table model bind to OData or JSON?

Comment: @TakaoBaltazar it's bound to OData

Answer (score 0):

```
this.byId("Table").setModel(oModel);
this.getView().byId('Table').rerender();
```

Set the model to the table and call the function rerender()